# Simple regex question (C#, SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql-server, regex, winforms, sql-injection

I have some Regex, it looks like this:

```
string regexForDrop = @"^((%27)|'|(\-\-))\s*(d|%64|%44)(r|%72|%52)(o|%6F|%4F)(p|%70|%50)$";
```

It works fine, when i write to the input "--drop", but it does not works, when i write "drop table users" or something like that. I need that it would be working, no matter what comes after "--drop". How i can implement that?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to prevent SQL injection attacks here?

Comment: I would highly advise against using a regex as a method of security for SQL injection.  It's a recipe for getting hacked

Comment: Even if it works for "--drop", what about "--truncate" or any host of other evil things someone could do.

Comment: -1 for being one of the most stupid ideas ever.

Comment: Yes, I know about SP, I just do some research for studies about regex to.

Comment: @Vytass999: you might want to mention that next time,or people will think you're a moron (it does kinda look like a stupid idea, without knowing the background). ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string regexForDrop = @"^((%27)|'|(\-\-))\s*(d|%64|%44)(r|%72|%52)(o|%6F|%4F)(p|%70|%50).*$";
```

? or without the `$`

Comment: +1, whatever @Vytas999 reason, you wrote the code to solve it

Answer (score 6):

It seems you trying to prevent a sql injection attack. For this use Parameterized Queries this way you don't need to check for injections.

Good Read:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/09/30/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Guard-Against-SQL-Injection-Attacks.aspx

Comment: Yes, I know about SP, i just do some research for studies about regex to. Thanks for the link, I would read it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the '$' at the end of your regular expression. $ matches the end of the input string.